# Missing "Publish as Azure Cloud Service"

Tags: eclipse, azure, cloud

I want to make a simple dynamic web project with Eclipse and to publish it as an Azure Cloud Service.

I follow this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-toolkit-for-eclipse-creating-a-hello-world-application.

I have downloaded the trial version of Microsoft Azure.
I have installed Azure Toolkit for Eclipse in Help->Install New Software, but when I right click on my project and then I select the Azure menu, it contains only two options:

- Publish as Azure Web App
- Publish as Docker Container

So, why there's not the option "Publish as Azure Cloud Service" ? Can someone help me please ?

Comment: AFAIK, at low level you can consider web app and web services to be same. Web app are for human to machine interactions and services for machine to machine interactions. In nut shell, web app may have combination of GUI for human interaction and exposed APIs for machine to machine interaction. You can deploy it as azure web app, considering that you might be having some exposed APIs which in your case happens to be Cloud services.

Comment: @t6nand: Cloud Services are a product in itself in Azure. It is not a general name for web services.

Comment: Thanks @t6nand, I know what you tell me. But if two different option are available, I think that it is better to use Publish as Cloud Service rather than Publish as web App.

Comment: @dona Have you found an Answer?

Comment: No @Magu, I'm not using Azure anymore

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a late post

1. Open the eclipse
2. Click on Help and then select 'Eclipse marketplace'
3. Search for Azure keyword and click on lens icon.
4. You will find an option "Azure toolkit for eclipse". Install it.
5. Eclispe will restart, if it doesn't do it manually.
6. You can now find the Publish as Azure Cloud service by right clicking the project.

[image]